# I want to android app A to communicate to android app B using tcp method

Tags: android, tcpclient

I want to make two android application that communicate each other using tcp in the same device itself .

Say when a user from Android A app. clicks a button it must bring Android app B to the front and show a message from Android A and when user clicks a button on Android B ( say processed finished ) it must get behind and Android A must come to the front of the display

How can this be done can it be done by tcp method or what exactly I must use for this

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).